# If a group has a continuous inverse operator and acts on itself by conjugation continuously, when is it necessarily a topological group?

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups

I encountered the notion of a [topological group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group) and a [continuous group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_group_action) recently and have a basic question about a possible alternative characterization and whether it captures the same notion or not. I'm curious whether a group $G$ (where $^{-1}$ is continuous) acting continuously on itself by conjugation is sufficient to be a topological group.

---

**Is there a further non-topological property that we could impose on our group $G$ so that $G$ acting on itself continuously by conjugation would be equivalent to $G$ being a topological group.
For example, we know that $G$ cannot be Abelian.**

---

Suppose I have a group $G = (G_0, ^{-1}, *)$ equipped with a topology $\tau$. $G$ is a [topological group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group) if and only if the inverse map $^{-1} : G_0 \to G_0$ is continuous and $G$ acts continuously on itself by left multiplication (or equivalently right multiplication).

However, in addition to acting on itself by left or right multiplication, every group acts on itself by conjugation.

If I know that $^{-1} : G_0 \to G_0$ is continuous and $G$ acts on itself by conjugation continuously (i.e. $x \mapsto gxg^{-1}$ is continuous for all $g$), what further constraints do I need to impose so that $G$ is a topological group?

Comment: I suspect not. If $G$ is abelian, then the conjugation map is the identity and you would have only the structure of the inverse map which isn't enough for a topological group.

Comment: I'm going to amend my question slightly and ask if there's a further non-topological property we can impose on our groups where showing that conjugation is continuous would be sufficient. I think this is okay since I'm the only one who's answered so far.

Comment: So you have two options: you constrain the topology (which probably defeats the purpose) or you constrain your group structure somehow. Typically what one does in functional analysis regarding topologies is define them such that they are the weakest topology for which (something), e.g. the topology on a topological group is the weakest topology such that the group operations are continuous. This ultimately means you define the topology via the continuity in a way, similar happens with the weak topologies.

Comment: So barring that, you would want to constrain your group somehow. You know it can't be abelian. Since you're interested in conjugation, maybe what you want to do is drop down to something about the subgroups?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what conditions I can impose on my group that are group theoretic, but I guess constraining the topology is okay too. I really like your comment. Is taking a fixed group up-front, picking a basis for $\tau$, and then closing it under arbitrary unions, finite intersections, and inverses and multiplication by group elements (because they're continuous by fiat) a typical way of constructing a topological group?